# Selected Vertex into Edges Selection in Maya API?

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to convert the select vertex into edges selection in maya api… any suggestion from you?

Just like polyListComponentConversion in cmds? :)

thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use `MItMeshVertex` and collect the connected edges:

```
import maya.api.OpenMaya as om

# Assume we've created a poly cube and selected vertices 2, 3, 5.
selection = om.MGlobal.getActiveSelectionList()

assert selection.length() == 1
node, component = selection.getComponent(0)

edges = set()
it = om.MItMeshVertex(node, component)
while not it.isDone():
    connected_edges = it.getConnectedEdges()
    edges.update(connected_edges)
    it.next()

print(edges)
```

This should print:

```
set([1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9])
```

`polyListComponentConversion` should give the same result:

```
cmds.select('pCube1.vtx[2:3]', replace=True)
cmds.select('pCube1.vtx[5]', add=True)
edges = cmds.polyListComponentConversion(fromVertex=True, toEdge=True)
print(edges)`
```

```
[u'pCube1.e[1:2]', u'pCube1.e[4:7]', u'pCube1.e[9]']
```

That expands to the same set of indices.